# A flawed argument involving the theorem Invariance of Domain

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

One consequence of the theorem [Invariance of Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) is the following proposition: if $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ and $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ are open subsets and $f:U\to V$ is a homeomorphism, then $m=n$.

Please, taking into consideration the previous proposition, find the error in the following argument: Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x)=(x,0)$. This map is injective. Therefore $\tilde f:\mathbb{R}\to f(\mathbb{R}),x \mapsto f(x)$ is a bijection and its inverse is $g:f(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R},\, (x,0)\mapsto x$. It's easy to verify that $\tilde f$ and $g$ are continous. Therefore $\tilde f:\mathbb{R}\to f(\mathbb{R})$ is a homeomorphism. Also, since $g$ is continuous and $\mathbb{R}$ is open, then $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=f(\mathbb{R})$ is an open set. But that contradicts that proposition above. **Where's the mistake?** I couldn't find it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is that $f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In fact, any ball of positive radius around any point of this set will contain points outside of it.

The argument "$g$ is continuous and $\mathbb{R}$ is open, so $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=f(\mathbb{R})$ must be open" is false, but subtly so. The key is to look at the definition of continuity: a map between topological spaces $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if, for all open subsets $V\subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(V)\subseteq X$ is open. But $g$ is a map $f(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. So all continuity tells us is that, since $\mathbb{R}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=f(\mathbb{R})$ is an open subset of $f(\mathbb{R})$, but this is trivial. The notion of openness always depends on the ambient space.

Comment: But $g$ is continuous. Therefore $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=f(\mathbb{R})$ must be open, right?

Comment: $g^{-1}(\mathbb R)$ is open **in the domain of** $g$, namely $f(\mathbb R)$.  It is not open in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I saw that proposition, which is in my question, in a book about topology. So that proposition is incorrect in case $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ and $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ are proper subsets, right?

Comment: No, why would you come to that conclusion? The proposition is correct, I am merely explaining why what you are considering does not contradict the proposition.

Comment: @Thorgott Let $\tau_{\mathbb{R}^m}$ and $\tau_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ be, respectively, the standard topologies of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. We always say that a map $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^m\to V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous with respect to the topologies  $\tau_{\mathbb{R}^m}|_U:=\{A\cap U:A\in\tau_{\mathbb{R}^m}\}$ and $\tau_{\mathbb{R}^n}|_V:=\{A\cap V:A\in\tau_{\mathbb{R}^n}\}$. Because of that we fell in the case I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what your point is.

Comment: @Thorgott I'm saying that that proposition isn't correct because $\tilde f:\mathbb{R}\to f(\mathbb{R})$ is a homeomorphism with respect to the topologies $\tau_\mathbb{R}$ (this is the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$) and $\tau:=\big\{A\cap f(\mathbb{R}):A\in\tau_{\mathbb{R}^2}\big\}$.

Comment: That does not contradict the proposition, because $f(\mathbb{R})$ is *not* an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks a lot!